# iOS - make UIImage take the same size as UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uiimage

I create a custom bar button using

```
+ (UIBarButtonItem *)barBtnItem:(id)target action:(SEL)action imageName:(NSString *)imageName frame:(CGRect)frame
{
    UIButton *btn =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn addTarget:target action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [btn setFrame:frame];
    UIBarButtonItem *barBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];
    return barBtn;
}
```

The frame is of size

```
CGRectMake(0, 0, 22, 22)
```

However, I think due to aspect ratio, my image gets smaller but is correctly centered in the UIButton

However, I want the image to become the same size as of UIButton.

Can I do that?

I used XCode 7 and tried its slicing feature. But I could not make it work.

If I could do it via code?

I also looked at UIEdgeinsets but I do not fully understand cap/insets concepts.

Comment: Both answers were correct. However the values for insets needed to be negative to expand image. 0 did not work as it does not do anything. If I set the insets value to -5, I got desired behavior.

Comment: if you don't mind set it as background image, you can try this  https://github.com/AlexHsieh/ButtonAppearance

Answer (score 1):

Set the content mode of the button to `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill`.

```
btn.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill
btn.imageView.frame = btn.bounds
```

Comment: I made an adjustment.

Answer (score 1):

check after write below code  :

```
btn.contentMode= UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
btn.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
btn.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Still not work then try below line of code. Set background image of `UIButton` instead of image.

```
+ (UIBarButtonItem *)barBtnItem:(id)target action:(SEL)action imageName:(NSString *)imageName frame:(CGRect)frame
{

UIButton *btn =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn addTarget:target action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[btn setFrame:frame];
UIBarButtonItem *barBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];
return barBtn;
}
```

if not work use below line of code :

```
 UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(handleBack:)];
```

Comment: Edited my answer `UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(handleBack:)];`. Check it

Comment: it does stretch..but I find other issues. I will update on this after some more investigation

Answer (score 0):

you can do it through AutoLayouts !!! set image Constraints from top , bottom , left , right equal to Button !!